# tex capacity exceeds when adding hyperlinks to personal data in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to add hyper link and change the color in the personal info section of my moderncv classic template, such as homepage, email and address but I encounter this error:

```
Tex capacity exceeded, sorry! [input stack size= 5000]
```

here's my MWE

```
      \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

    % moderncv themes
    \moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
    \moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
    %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
    %\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

    % character encoding
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0.4,0.6}  
    \usepackage{amssymb} 
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}
                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
    %\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

    % adjust the page margins
    \usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
     \usepackage{changepage}
     \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{setspace}
            \newcommand*{\Skype}{\href{skype:example?add}{example}} 
            \newcommand{\Absender}[1][\normalsize]{\Skype} 
            \newcommand\narrowstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{-50}\lsstyle}
            \newcommand\spacedstyle[1]{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{#1}\lsstyle}
            \newcommand\normalstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{0}\lsstyle}

            % personal data
            \name{example}{example}
            \address{\href{http://example.com}{\color{blue}lablabla,%
            }\makenewline \href{http://example2.com}{ \color{blue}lablabla} }{Tehran,}{Iran}


            \email{example@gmail.com}                               
            \homepage{\href{www.example.com}{\color{blue}{www.example.com}}}                         
            \extrainfo{Skype:\color{blue} \Absender }                 

           \begin{document}
\end{document}
```

.....

what Should I do?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: sure I will edit it now

Comment: @samcarter done

Comment: Your MWE is not complete, please add the documentclass you are using and the minimal code necessary to show your problem. We need to be able to compile it. Instead of your personal data, put some fake infos.

Comment: @CarLaTeX
Sorry about that, I'm a bit new to LaTeX, I guess it should work now that I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not output any page. However, `moderncv` already uses `\href` to output the argument of `\href`. So you cannot use `\href` inside this argument.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0.4,0.6}  
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}
                   % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Already loaded above!
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand*{\Skype}{\href{skype:example?add}{example}} 
\newcommand{\Absender}[1][\normalsize]{\Skype} 
\newcommand\narrowstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{-50}\lsstyle}
\newcommand\spacedstyle[1]{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{#1}\lsstyle}
\newcommand\normalstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{0}\lsstyle}

% personal data
\name{example}{example}
\address{\href{http://example.com}{\color{blue}lablabla,%
  }\makenewline \href{http://example2.com}{ \color{blue}lablabla} }{Tehran,}{Iran}

\email{example@gmail.com}                               
\homepage{www.example.com}% Don't use \href in the argument of \homepage!
\extrainfo{Skype:\color{blue} \Absender }                 

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

If you want the links in `blue`, just pass options `colorlinks` and `urlcolor=blue` to `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand*{\Skype}{\href{skype:example?add}{example}} 
\newcommand{\Absender}[1][\normalsize]{\Skype} 
\newcommand\narrowstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{-50}\lsstyle}
\newcommand\spacedstyle[1]{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{#1}\lsstyle}
\newcommand\normalstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{0}\lsstyle}

\name{example}{example}
\address{\href{http://example.com}{lablabla,%
  }\makenewline \href{http://example2.com}{lablabla}}{Tehran,}{Iran}

\email{example@gmail.com}                               
\homepage{www.example.com}
\extrainfo{Skype:\color{blue} \Absender }

\PassOptionsToPackage{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) for more information about the available options.

Comment: @Ghazal.S In this case you [should vote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) or even accept the answer.